# c# listview disable resizing column mode for user

Tags: c#, listview, resize

I use listview but prefer the column size to be fixed. Have no idea how to do this. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am hoping that you are using winforms...then you can do like this...

by calling listview AutoResizeColumn  property .....

take a look at this link for [more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.autoresizecolumn.aspx)

```
    private ListView resizingListView = new ListView();
    private Button button1 = new Button();

    private void InitializeResizingListView()
    {
        // Set location and text for button.
        button1.Location = new Point(100, 15);
        button1.Text = "Resize";
        button1.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);

        // Set the ListView to details view.
        resizingListView.View = View.Details;

        //Set size, location and populate the ListView.
        resizingListView.Size = new Size(200, 100);
        resizingListView.Location = new Point(40, 40);
        resizingListView.Columns.Add("HeaderSize");
        resizingListView.Columns.Add("ColumnContent");
        ListViewItem listItem1 = new ListViewItem("Short");
        ListViewItem listItem2 = new ListViewItem("Tiny");
        listItem1.SubItems.Add(new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem( 
                listItem1, "Something longer"));
        listItem2.SubItems.Add(new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(
            listItem2, "Something even longer"));
        resizingListView.Items.Add(listItem1);
        resizingListView.Items.Add(listItem2);

        // Add the ListView and the Button to the form.
        this.Controls.Add(resizingListView);
        this.Controls.Add(button1);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        resizingListView.AutoResizeColumn(0, 
            ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize);
        resizingListView.AutoResizeColumn(1, 
            ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent);
    }
```